# How to get HTML input in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to read a html site in a string with kotlin.

But I cannot find how I even get the information from the website or which command I need for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code reads the content of http://www.android.com/ and outputs the text in the log.

```
val url = URL("http://www.android.com/")
val urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection

try {
  val text = urlConnection.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()
  Log.d("UrlTest", text)
} finally {
  urlConnection.disconnect()
}
```

See https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection on how interact with HTTP servers in Android.

Kotlin provides the extension methods `bufferedReader()` and `readText` which make reading streams more convenient.

Comment: Thank you, that already helps a lot.  Now the build finishes, but the programm crashes right after start
07-11 09:14:02.773 18325-18325/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hdmc.smartristraveller, PID: 18325
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at
android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:86)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:752)

Comment: It works now, I had to do it in another thread, so I did it for now in an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of Jsoup library 
[Jsoup html parser](https://jsoup.org/)